# Calling fgets while debugging under IDA Linux

Tags: ida, linux, debugging

I have `_fgets` call in a program I want to debug in IDA. My program receives `SIGTTIN` while calling it, that's normal. But when I mark to pass `SIGTTIN` to application, program waits for input in terminal, but neither pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, nor <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> stop reading from input. What should I do to finish the input?

Comment: What version of IDA are you using? If I'm not wrong, I fixed myself that in 6.3 or something.

Comment: @joxeankoret IDA 6.3. But there are no problems when debugging in GDB.

Comment: GDB is not IDA. Have you tried redirecting input? You can use in the arguments field "< some_file" to pass input to STDIN. Or if running via linux_remote you can run a command line like: $ linux_remote < some_file_with_inputs. This way no problem should arise.

Answer (score 5):

This problem can be avoided by calling IDA this way:

```
cat | idaq
```

Comment: Finally I can use IDA's debugger, thanks @jvoisin. I still do not understand why this command works, but it really works.